# File upload using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to upload a file using angular js and show various messages like processing, validating etc to the user while upload. How to achieve this using angular js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at `ng-file-upload`, an angular plugin that should be helpful for this.

https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

It also offers validation

> validation on file type/size, image width/height, video/audio duration and ng-required support.